# How to stack fruit in a neat pile

Tags: java, math, factorial

I've chosen Java for this case because the language is simple enough for anyone to translate.

What would be the mathematical algorithm to determine the number of fruit required on the bottom line to stack X number of fruits in a pattern like this? (ignoring power of 2's, which I stack in a square)

```
 *  1
 * 2 3          = 2
 *
 *  1 2
 * 3 4 5        = 3
 *
 *   1
 *  2 3
 * 4 5 6        = 3
 *
 *  1 2 3
 * 4 5 6 7      = 4
 *
 *   1 2
 *  3 4 5
 * 6 7 8 9      = 4
 *
 *    1
 *   2 3
 *  4 5 6
 * 7 8 9 X      = 4
 *
 *   1 2 3
 *  3 4 5 6
 * 7 8 9 X 1    = 5
```

Initially I thought it'd be easy, but as the numbers got higher I'm starting to think it's more of a factorial.

**Edit: Adding in the code translated from answer provided below by @templatetypedef**

```
private int _getBottomLineCount() {
    double insideSquareRoot = (8 * numberOfApples) +1;
    double squareRoot = Math.sqrt(insideSquareRoot);
    double val = (squareRoot -1) /2;

    return (int) Math.ceil(val); // Round it up to nearest whole number
}
```

Comment: Look at it the reverse way first.  Answer the question, "What is the maximum number of fruits you can stack if the number of fruits on the bottom line is _n_"?  Once you figure that out, you should be able to use high-school algebra to answer your original question.

Comment: would you mind going just one step farther? Or just clarifying whether a partially empty row is okay? If you're fine with partially empty rows, the current answer works, but if not it takes a little bit more effort.

Comment: Also, how do you stack odd powers of 2 in a square?

Comment: If you're actually going to stack fruit, you should do so in three dimensions.

Comment: @Teepeemm It depends on the fruit.  I think you could stack bananas in the way the questioner describes.  Oranges, not so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of fruit in a pyramid of height n is given by the nth *triangular number*, given by the equation

> T<sub>n</sub> = n(n + 1) / 2

For example, a pyramid of height 2 holds 2(2 + 1) / 2 = 3 fruit. A pyramid of height 4 holds 4(4 + 1) / 2 = 10 fruit.

If you have k fruit to put into a stack, you're looking for the smallest number n such that T<sub>n</sub> ≥ k. You can solve for this directly:

> T<sub>n</sub> = k
>
> n(n + 1) / 2 = k
>
> n<sup>2</sup> + n = 2k
>
> n<sup>2</sup> + n - 2k = 0

Using the quadratic formula gives

> n = (-1 ±√(1 + 8k)) / 2

The negative root here can be ignored, so your number n should be given by

> n = (√(8k + 1) - 1) / 2

This number might be not be an integer, in which case you want to round up.

Let's try some examples. Suppose that you have 9 fruit to stack. We can evaluate the formula above to get

> n = (√(72 + 1) - 1) / 2 = (√(73) - 1) / 2 = 3.772001873

Rounding up gives k = 4, so you'd need a stack of height 4.

Suppose you have 137 fruit to stack. The same formula gives back n = 16.060495162, so you'd need a stack of height 17 to store the fruit.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The triangular/pyramid height was JUST what I needed! Initially I ran across some quirks in the code but it was an extra +1 I accidentally added. Your math checks out, thank you for that great explanation (and examples)!